# Slow Display with Intel 855GM After Upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, xorg

I just upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 on my Dell Inspiron 700m.  The display is now much slower than it used to be. For example, when I drag a Nautilus window around with my mouse, the motion of the window significantly lags the mouse pointer (e.g. if I move the window up and down, the pointer and window motion will be almost 180 degrees out of phase).

From dmesg:

```
[    0.419302] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel 855GM Chipset
[    0.419327] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 131072K total, 131072K     mappable
[    0.420659] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 16384K stolen memory
[    0.424248] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 128M @ 0xe8000000
```

And from Xorg.0.log:

```
[    48.909] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    48.909] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    48.953] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    48.953] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    48.954]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.17.0
[    48.954]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    48.954]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    48.954] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server
[    48.954] (++) using VT number 7

[    48.956] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    48.956] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    48.956] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    48.956] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[    48.956] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    48.956] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    48.956] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[    48.956] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
[    48.956] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    48.956] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    48.956] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    48.956] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    48.956] (**) intel(0): Option "DRI" "true"
[    48.957] (II) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) 852GM/855GM
[    48.957] (--) intel(0): Chipset: "852GM/855GM"
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): Relaxed fencing disabled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): Wait on SwapBuffers? enabled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): Triple buffering? enabled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): 3D buffers tiled
[    48.957] (**) intel(0): SwapBuffers wait enabled
```

Nothing sticks out on first gloss.  It looks like it's detecting the proper chipset and loading the corresponding driver. My hunch is that it's using software rendering when before at least HW acceleration was used.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to this bug: [Poor performance on Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/984452) or at least in my case the poor graphics performance is because of it. If you think that it may be also related to your problem, you could go and vote for it as shown here: [how to vote](http://goo.gl/wqOjf) (*you have to be **logged in***). Hopefully it will get fixed sooner.